# .NETBlogEngine Error with theming

Tags: c#, asp.net, blogengine.net

when I'm trying to run blogengine with new theme i just got this error now i can't get run the BE2.5
 here is the error

> Item has already been added. Key in dictionary:
>   'enablereferrertracking'  Key being added: 'enablereferrertracking'

i think something wrong data in database because same copy with another database work please help me to fix this issue.

and here is the stack trace

> [ArgumentException: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary:
>   'enablereferrertracking'  Key being added: 'enablereferrertracking']
>   System.Collections.Hashtable.Insert(Object key, Object nvalue, Boolean
>   add) +9352427    System.Collections.Hashtable.Add(Object key, Object
>   value) +11
>   System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary.Add(String key, String
>   value) +60    BlogEngine.Core.Providers.DbBlogProvider.LoadSettings()
>   in
>   E:\Projects\BlogEngine_25_Release\BlogEngine\DotNetSlave.BusinessLogic\Providers\DbBlogProvider.cs:1097
>   BlogEngine.Core.BlogSettings.Load() in
>   E:\Projects\BlogEngine_25_Release\BlogEngine\DotNetSlave.BusinessLogic\BlogSettings.cs:1301
>   BlogEngine.Core.BlogSettings..ctor() in
>   E:\Projects\BlogEngine_25_Release\BlogEngine\DotNetSlave.BusinessLogic\BlogSettings.cs:84
>   BlogEngine.Core.BlogSettings.GetInstanceSettings(Blog blog) in
>   E:\Projects\BlogEngine_25_Release\BlogEngine\DotNetSlave.BusinessLogic\BlogSettings.cs:117
>   BlogEngine.Core.Web.HttpModules.WwwSubDomainModule.ContextBeginRequest(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) in
>   E:\Projects\BlogEngine_25_Release\BlogEngine\DotNetSlave.BusinessLogic\Web\HttpModules\WwwSubDomainModule.cs:118
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +148    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just an idea.

There's a settings.xml file somewhere. Edit it, and see if there are two (or more) tags named enablereferrertracking. Delete until there's only one, and see if that helped.

You have to restart the app-domain, since it loads files into memory. So either iisreset, or close the development web-server or whatever you use.

Comment: i'm using mssql for datastore also did delete the entry. but not working.

Comment: but the tip was help me to check be_Setting table on sql after deleted all the redundant values now work pretty good thanks MartinHN

Comment: Cool. You could modify `BlogSettings` class, to check the dictionary for an item before adding it. Would add nice robustness to the app. Maybe even delete the entry, if it has already been added.